# What are advantages of setting largeHeap to true?

Tags: android, android-memory, android-largeheap

I have an application with large number of classes & also many libraries are included, I am setting `android:largeHeap="true"` as i am getting memory issue, My Manifest file code is attached.

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="My Huge Application"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>
```

I had to ask that is this a good practice?
Kindly suggest advantages and disadvantages (pros and cons) of using it.

Comment: if you need large memory for your app like games 3dmodels etc

Comment: 50 classes is not that many.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: if you are using some service or any other application apps inside your app which consumes memory then your app will have issue of memory like camera is the most common issue developer's face while using app or if you have lot of variable which is consuming memory or static variable may also be the reason for that.

Comment: The number of classes is not important. What typically takes a lot of memory is bitmaps. See "[Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap)".

Comment: Methods matter, classes don't, as per official documentation if app contains total number of methods 64K then use multidex enabled=true.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Way too late for the party  here, but i will offer my 0.02$ anyways.
**It's not a good idea to use** `android:largeHeap="true"` here's the extract from google that explains it,

> However, the ability to request a large heap is intended only for a
>   small set of apps that can justify the need to consume more RAM (such
>   as a large photo editing app). Never request a large heap simply
>   because you've run out of memory and you need a quick fix—you should
>   use it only when you know exactly where all your memory is being
>   allocated and why it must be retained. Yet, even when you're confident
>   your app can justify the large heap, you should avoid requesting it to
>   whatever extent possible. Using the extra memory will increasingly be
>   to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage
>   collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when
>   task switching or performing other common operations.

here's the complete link of the documentation
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

> UPDATE

After working excrutiatingly with `out of memory errors` i would say adding this to the manifest to avoid the oom issue is not a sin, also like @Milad points out below it does not affect the normal working of the app

> UPDATE 2

Here are a few **tips to deal** with `out of memory errors`

1) Use these callback that android gives **`onLowMemory`**, **`onTrimMemory(int)`**  and clear the cache of image like (picasso, glide, fresco....) you can read more about them [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html)
2) compress your files(images, pdf)
3) read about how to handle bitmap more efficiently [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)
4) Use lint regularly before production pushes to ensure code is sleek and 
   not bulky

Comment: Why do you say "it does not affect the normal working of the app"? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37249905/199364) discusses some consequences. Elsewhere, I've seen even worse timing measured for largeHeap GC on some apps.

Comment: @Mightian, My app does contain lots of image galleries, including carousel works, so for that should it be genuine to use android:largeHeap="true" ?

Answer (score 71):

I think this is a very effective question, and let me add some details about advantages and disadvantages of using this option.

**What You Get :**

- Obviously, you get larger heap, which means decreasing risk of `OutOfMemoryError`.

**What You Lose :**

- **You may lose some frames, which can cause a visible hitching**. Larger heap makes garbage collections take longer. Because the garbage collector basically has to traverse your entire live set of objects. Usually, garbage collection pause time is about 5ms, and you may think few milliseconds are not a big deal. But every millisecond count. Android device has to update its screen in every 16 ms and longer GC time might push your frame processing time over the 16 millisecond barrier, which can cause a visible hitching.
- **Also switching apps will become slower**. Android system may kill processes in the LRU cache beginning with the process least recently used, but also giving some consideration toward which processes are most memory intensive. So if you use larger heap, your process would more likely to be killed when it's backgrounded, which means it may take longer time when users want to switch from other apps to yours. Also other backgrounded processes will more likely to be kicked out when your process is foreground, because your app require larger memory. It means switching from your app to other apps also takes longer.

**Conclusion :**

Avoid using `largeHeap` option as much as possible. It may cost you hard-to-notice performance drop and bad user experience.

Answer (score 21):

If you *must* use (and retain) a large amount of memory, then yes, you can and should use `android:largeHeap="true"`.  But if you do use it, you should be prepared to have your app flushed from memory whenever other apps are in the foreground.

By "be prepared," I mean that you should design for that likelihood, so that your `onStop()` and `onResume()` methods are written as efficiently as possible, while ensuring that all pertinent state is saved and restored in a manner that presents a seamless appearance to the user.

There are three methods that relate to this parameter: `maxMemory()`, `getMemoryClass()`, and `getLargeMemoryClass()`.

For most devices, `maxMemory()` will represent a similar value to `getMemoryClass()` by default, although the latter is expressed in megabytes, while the former is expressed in bytes.

When you use the `largeHeap` parameter, `maxMemory()` will be increased to a device-specific higher level, while `getMemoryClass()` will remain the same.

`getMemoryClass()` does not constrain your heap size, but it tells you the amount of heap you *should* use if you want your app to function *comfortably* and *compatibly* within the limits of the particular device on which you are running.

`maxMemory()`, by contrast, *does* constrain your heap size, and so you do gain access to additional heap through increasing its value, and `largeHeap` does increase that value.  However, the increased amount of heap is still limited, and that limit will be device-specific, which means that the amount of heap available to your app will vary, depending on the resources of the device on which your app is running.  So, using `largeHeap` is not an invitation for your app to abandon all caution and oink its way through the all-you-can-eat buffet.

Your app can discover exactly how much memory would be made available on a particular device through using the `largeHeap` parameter by invoking the method `getLargeMemoryClass()`.  The value returned is in megabytes.

This earlier post includes a discussion of the `largeHeap` parameter, as well as a number of examples of what amounts of heap are made available with and without its usage, on several specific Android devices:

[Detect application heap size in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630158/detect-application-heap-size-in-android/9428660#9428660)

I have not deployed any of my own apps with this parameter set to true.  However, I have some memory-intensive code in one of my apps for compiling a set of optimization-related parameters, that runs only during development.  I add the `largeHeap` parameter only during development, in order to avoid out of memory errors while running this code.  But I remove the parameter (and the code) prior to deploying the app.

Comment: _"abandon all caution and oink its way through the all-you-can-eat buffet"_ 

Answer (score 18):

Actually [android:largeHeap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) is the instrument for increasing your allocated memory to app.

**There is no clear definition of the need to use this flag. If you need more memory - Android provides you with a tool to increase it. But necessity of using, you define yourself.**

Comment: yes there is a clear definition refer this link https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html

Comment: @war_Hero - maybe that article has changed its contents?  There is no mention of largeHeap in it.

Answer (score 18):

> I have an App with almost 50 classes

I don't think this makes much problem. The reason why you've got outOfMemory error is usually loading too much images in your app or something like that. If you are unhappy to use large heap you must find a way to optimize using memory.

You can also use Image Loading Libraries such as [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/), [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). All of them have the feature of image caching in memory and/or on disk.

Comment: for image loading i generally recommend picaso or universal image loader

Comment: Glide is better and a bit more optimised then Picasso

Comment: @DamienPraca I don't think so, at least if you correctly use tags (setTag(), pauseTag(), resumeTag()) in Picasso.

Answer (score 4):

Whether your application's processes should be created with a large Dalvik heap. This applies to all processes created for the application. It only applies to the first application loaded into a process; if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option consistently or they will have unpredictable results.

Most apps should not need this and should instead focus on reducing their overall memory usage for improved performance. Enabling this also does not guarantee a fixed increase in available memory, because some devices are constrained by their total available memory.

Comment: this is the description of android:largeHeap, from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap