# Skipped 49 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am inflating Views (not fragments) in my viewpager implementation. My main class extends Activity.
I face this error when I try to swipe screen from my app or

`at com.example.app.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:47)`

and

```
01-04 16:44:35.5278614-8614/com.parsizabanan.app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4195ee48)
01-04 16:44:35.5278614-8614/com.parsizabanan.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FatAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.parsizabanan.app, PID: 8614
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInfl    ater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.parsizabanan.app.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:47)
at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1021)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1955)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1151)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1333)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1038)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5890)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInfl ater.java:56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.parsizabanan.app.CustomPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(CustomPagerAdapter.java:47)
at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1021)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(Rel    ativeLayout.java:719)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16574)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1955)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1151)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1333)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1038)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5890)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:610)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.cre    ateFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2150)
```

CustomPagerAdapter:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflaterinflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLatER_SERVICE);

    int resId = 0;
    switch (position) {
        case 0: {
            resId = R.layout.lab;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            resId = R.layout.lab;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            resId = R.layout.etela;
            break;
        }
        case 3: {
            resId = R.layout.ticket;
            break;
        }
        case 4: {
            resId = R.layout.product;
            break;
        }
        case 5: {
            resId = R.layout.about;
            break;
        }

    }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

}

@Override
public Parcelable saveSt    ate() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 6;
}
```

MyActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
ViewPager myPager = null;
ImageButton contact = null;
ImageButton about = null;
ImageButton lab = null;
ImageButton product = null;
ImageButton ticket = null;
ImageButton etela = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    CustomPagerAdapter adapter = new CustomPagerAdapter();
    myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.customviewpager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(5);

    myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, flo    at v, int i2) {
        }

        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        }

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    switch (myPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            t1.start();
        }
    });

}
```

and is it lab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/lab1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You have an `OutOfMemoryError`. You need to determine why you are running out of memory.

Comment: check how many views are loading in main layout i think ur view object are not releasing memory .

Comment: What size bitmaps are you loading?

Comment: Are you testing your APP in a Android Emulator? I meet the similar log when I test my APP on a emulator, but it just gone when I use real device.

Comment: @Simon totally load is about 1.2 MB

Comment: @YanAn I use and test only real device (LG G3)

Comment: @JaswinderWadali Thanks, How can I remove the unnecessary objects while showing each layout?

Comment: CHCEK ANSWER 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664155/dynamically-add-and-remove-view-to-viewpager

Comment: @JaswinderWadali BAD NEWS THERE IS NO ANIMATION IN THIS CASE

Comment: The file size is not relevant.  What is the bitmap size (height and width).

Comment: Each one of those needs about 3MB of memory (height x width x 4 bytes).  You need to scale those bitmaps when you read them.

Answer (score 1):

Using large images could cause this error. Its highly recommended to reduce images sizes and then load them to ImageViews.

Also there is an other way to request android to give your application more memory by adding the following to the manifest . But this is not recommended. For more information look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396892/androidlargeheap-true-in-mainifast-advantages) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html).

```
<application
    ...
    android:largeHeap="true"
    ...
>

...

</application>
```