# Out of Memoryerror android

Tags: android, memory-leaks

[image]

E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 42469452 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 31MB until OOM"

I got this issue but for what its saying outofmemoryError I'm not getting.So any one can help out to solve this issue.

**Please do not down vote question As I am not getting for what the issue is been created.**

Comment: What might be causing it? Some context/code would definitely help.

Comment: post complete stack trace

Comment: maybe you're dealing with Bitmap, you can't solve this issue unless you reduce the picture's size. Could you post the code where you catch this error ?

Comment: I would recommend you to use glide or picasso library to handle image loading

Comment: @L.Swifter I am using Picasso to show profile picture only there is not any large bitmap.and yes background image size is 151KB for all screen.

Comment: Can you post your StackTrace?

Comment: remve the image clean project and rebuild paste again image

Answer (score 1):

Reduce image size use this links....

**For PNG**

[CompressPng](http://compresspng.com/)

[TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/)

**For JPG**

[CompressJpeg](http://compressjpeg.com/)

[TinyJpg](https://tinyjpg.com/)

**Note:-make image size less than 50 kb if possible ......**

enjoy coding.........

Comment: If I using 151KB file for image background will it cause outof memory. I am using this background for all screen of my app

Comment: @priyankaChauhan we can tell you anything without seening you logcat? all other are guesses?

Comment: @SohailZahid can you please check it. I have uploaded logcat

Comment: @priyankaChauhan let me know if your problem is not solved after reducing size of image than it problem with Picasso may be

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable you MultiDex Support as you see the message in logcat.

[**To Enable Multidex click here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

you might still face issue if some other issue also exist after enabling it try if still face problem comment below.

**Modify your Gradle file:**

```
android {
    ....

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
            } else {
                dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
            }
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes I have done all steps from accepted answer of link

Comment: public class AppConfig extends MultiDexApplication {
} is it necessary ? I am extending Application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120394/discussion-between-sohail-zahid-and-priyanka-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

put `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest like this

`<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

NOTE: This might result in temporary solution or no solution at all, in that case please follow @sushildlh methods to reduce image sizes.
**Also this is neither the best nor the recommended process of doing it but it is an effective solution**. [click here to know more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396892/what-are-advantages-of-setting-largeheap-to-true)

Comment: This isn't a good idea, unless you are building a large image editing app or something you shouldn't include largeHeap in your manifest file. All you are doing is hiding the issue.