# App closing with exception on all Mi devices(On MIUI ROM)

Tags: android, debugging

I made an app and its working on all the emulators and phones except Mi devices which have MIUI. Exception is arising while setting content view. I'm attaching the logcat and java file.

**Java Code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final int width = display.getWidth();
    final int height = display.getHeight();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (width==720)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    else
        setContentView(R.layout.main_copy);
    System.out.println("Game Option A Screen (MainActivity.class)");
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
     p1 = sp.getString("player1Name", "Player 1");
     p2 = sp.getString("player2Name", "Player 2");
     p1pokemon = sp.getString("player1pokemon", "");
     p2pokemon = sp.getString("player2Pokemon", "");
     rl=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
}
```

**LogCat**

```
8348-8348/bt4u.com.pokemonbattles E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 20971884 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 19MB until OOM"
        8348-8348/bt4u.com.pokemonbattles E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: bt4u.com.pokemonbattles, PID: 8348
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bt4u.com.pokemonbattles/bt4u.com.pokemonbattles.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class <unknown>
        t android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
        at bt4u.com.pokemonbattles.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:686) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at bt4u.com.pokemonbattles.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) 
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20971884 byte allocation with 16777120 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
        at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2822)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2523)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2421)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:751)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3740)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:498)
        at android.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:285)
        at android.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:281)
        at android.widget.GridLayout.<init>(GridLayout.java:277)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:686) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at bt4u.com.pokemonbattles.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2285) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5276) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706) 
    8348-8348/bt4u.com.pokemonbattles I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8348 SIG: 9
```

Comment: go through this it help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38822658/5305430

Comment: But it is working on every other phone and emulator just not on devices like Redmi Note 3, Mi4i. And my images are of size like 4kb-15kb

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` this error coming sometimes becoz of image size .Will you please tell us line of exception coming ??

Comment: Can you post your XML here.. its says there is something wrong in XML Line `21`