# imageview in xml causing app to crash on launch

Tags: android, xml, imageview

First off let me apologize for any layout/formatting errors, I'm doing this on my cell.

That being said, I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the below xml. With it in my layout file, the app crashes on load, but if I cut it out, the app loads and runs fine.   Any help in figuring out the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The drawables are all .jpg files in the drawable folder. 
Note: This section is cut from within another vertical linearlayout

Not sure if can/how to copy logcat from Aide. However, the logcat finally popped and it is an out of memory exception.  I will try reducing the image size and come back.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Current Favorites"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mia_sollis"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mia Sollis"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/pepper_kester"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pepper Kester"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/jayme"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Jayme Langford"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your LogCat.

Comment: There is none to post, I am developing this small app using Aide on my cell, and the logcat never seems to work with 'crash on launch' type problems.

Comment: Probably an out of memory error. Use an image loading library to load the image at runtime

Comment: Are you on Android Studio?

Comment: @sufian - No, I'm on Aide for android

Comment: @cricket_007 - I've almost never used images before, and the few times I have, I've had no issues. I would even begin to know how to do what you said, unfortunately.

Comment: what are you doing with that imageView

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions you need to find out how you can view the LogCat. Try [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) to get the crash log, and updated it in your question.

Comment: @abhaybohra - Absolutely nothing, no coded modification or anything, just want 3 images side by side, with titles under them,  as this xml snippet should do

Comment: Not sure about getting this in AIDE, but for example.  http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @sufian - I'd kill to have Catlog, but it requires root, and I have not rooted this phone so as not to lose Samsung pay (knox device)

Comment: @DEFSoftwareSolutions testing device and not rooted? Ah. Try running the APK on Genymotion or emulator and post the LogCat. Without that, it's just a guessing game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible answer is,

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mia_sollis"/>
```

image "mia_sollis" is too big  and hence is giving out of memory error.
Try out with smaller size image, it will solve your problem.

Comment: This was the issue, I resized the images to make them smaller and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reasons based on your XML layout:

1) You forgot to add this on top of your layout file

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

2) Second and the most important

**You have multiple root tag**, **TextView and LinearLayout** both of them is your root. However, you MUST have one root layout and inside it, do what ever you want.

Cheers!

Comment: As stated in OP, this xml snippet is cut from a larger xml.  The header tag is in the full xml, and the root tag is a relativelayout, withing that is a vertical linearlayout, within that is where I tried this.  I can edit OP to make that clearer if need be, sorry for bad formatting lol

Comment: Please add the full layout @DEFSoftwareSolutions. Otherwise, it's hard to determine. Sorry for not being helpful :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to post your Log

I guess

maybe the size of images is too big for your app memory.

add this to your `Application` tag in `Manifest`

```
<application
        .......
        android:largeHeap="true"
        ........ >
```

Comment: This post covers reasons that this isn't necessarily a good suggestion.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396892/what-are-advantages-of-setting-largeheap-to-true

Comment: I'll try this, standby