# ViewPager inside Fragment do not Showing ImageView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to make `carousel view` using `ViewPager` which is in `Fragment`.
`Fragment` is also showed by another `ViewPager` which is in `MainActivity`.

However, `ViewPager` in Fragment do not showing `ImageView`.
I think `ViewPager` is ok, because when I change `ViewPager`'s background and `ImageView`'s background respectively, only `ImageView`'s background was not showed.

Please help.

## MainActivity.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.activity;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.app.friend.FriendFragment;
import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.base.BaseActivity;
import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.app.home.HomeFragment;
import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.R;
import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.app.trend.TrendFragment;

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    View friendDrawer;
    ImageButton menuButton;
    ImageButton slidMenuBackButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //view custom action bar
        customActionbar();

        //initialize tab
        initTab();

        friendDrawer = (View) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        menuButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_button_menu);
        slidMenuBackButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sidemenu_button_close);

        //set MainPagerAdapter
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_veiwpager);
        MainPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        //drawer open by button on action bar
        draweOpnebyMenuButton();

        //drawer close by button on slide menu
        drawerClosebyBackButton();

    }

    /* /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                //
    //                    About UI                    //
    //                                                //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////// */

    public void customActionbar()
    {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.item_main_actionbar);
    }

    public void initTab()
    {
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tablayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("선물스토리"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("친구스토리"));
    }

    /* /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                                                //
    //                  About drawer                  //
    //                                                //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////// */

    public void draweOpnebyMenuButton()
    {
        menuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(friendDrawer);
            }
        });
    }

    public void drawerClosebyBackButton()
    {
        slidMenuBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(friendDrawer);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

BaseActivity is for convenient which extents AppCompatActivity.

## HomeFragment.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.app.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.R;
import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.model.HomeItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment
{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    VpAdapter adapter;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View hView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) hView.findViewById(R.id.home_viewPager);
        adapter = new VpAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) hView.findViewById(R.id.home_dotNavi_tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

        return hView;
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance()
    {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

}
```

## fragment_home.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/ut_std_main_mint_01">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_dotNavi_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/home_viewPager"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/btn_homebanner_round_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_buttoncontainer_tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/home_viewPager"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="4">
            <com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.widget.SquareButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.widget.SquareButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.widget.SquareButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.widget.SquareButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="기념일 별\n추천 선물"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="감정으로\n찾는 선물"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="브랜드\n선물"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="선물 기획전"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_giftfindbg_roundrect_selector"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:text="선물 준비 시작하기"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/ut_std_text_gray_01"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

## VpAdapter.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.app.home;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.R;

public class VpAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    private int[] sampleImg = new int[] { R.drawable.img_home_cardviewbg_01, R.drawable.img_home_cardviewbg_02 };

    public VpAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager)
    {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sampleImg.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return VpFragment.create(sampleImg[position]);
    }
}
```

## VpFragment.java

```java
package com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.app.home;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.rudolphriding.giftfriend.R;

/**
 * Created by LeeJihye on 2017-11-09.
 */

public class VpFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
{
    private int image;
    private ViewGroup rootView;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bitmapImg;
    BitmapFactory.Options options;

    public static VpFragment create(int image)
    {
        VpFragment fragment = new VpFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("image", image);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        image = getArguments().getInt("image");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_home_viewpager, container, false);
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        bitmapImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(rootView.getResources(), image, options);

        imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_ImageView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapImg);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

## item_home_viewpager.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_ImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/ut_std_text_gray_01"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set tablayout and viewpager in main activity is like this:

```
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        viewPager.setAdapter(jobTitlePagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Hope this help..If you have doubt then pls ask me.

Comment: Oh, tablayout is just for indicator, so I’m sure it is not a cause.

Comment: So what is the issue? can u plz explain me what you exactly want?

Comment: As I wrote, I used viewpager to show some images. However, imageview is not showing but viewpager is.

Comment: have set image src to display image?

Comment: Yes, if code is correct, I set image with `VpAdapter` and `VpFragment`.

Comment: you want image in which fragment? VPfragment?
Only one image is there in Vpfragment right?

Comment: No, I want to show image in `ViewPager` which is in `HomeFragment`. To show a image, I use `item_home_viewpager` which has `ImageView`.

Comment: Hi you are doing wrong in VPfragment code..You need to inflate item_home_viewpager file into home fragment .
No need viewpager in fragment..view pager is in activity only.

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception about bitmap limit of the device. This exception doesn't stop your app but you cannot see the background drawable because of device limit. Every device has it's own limit. Don't think your drawables are so small, if you have a lot of images on the screen, then you will reach that limit.

[On This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635904/4978534)
How to avoid the "Canvas: trying to draw too large (216090000bytes) bitmap." exception is explained.

I'm not telling this is your problem but it can be.

Comment: Thank you for kind reply! It could be, but I think the problem is that the `ImageView` which is in `VpFramgment` is not showing at all. But thanks to your answers, I found another fact. Thank you.