# My app keeps stopping / crashing in emulator (after OS reinstall)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am doing some Android courses and part of my assignments I have to build a mock-up music player app. The app doesn't have to have any functionality so it's mostly xml code.
While I try to run it in the emulator, the app keeps crashing with messages like: "Vibes has stopped" or "Vibes keeps stoping".

What might be important to add is that I recently reinstalled the os on my Mac (did a full wipe). I am now running macOS High Sierra. I had some compatibility problems with HAXM, but it was solved with the latest update from Intel on the HAXM component.
Java is installed, so I am not sure if there is anything else I am missing here.

I have also tried importing older projects, which worked before, and have the same issue. So based on this, I doubt that the code is the problem here.

Any advice is more than welcome! :-)

Here is manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.alexcojocaru.vibes">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Library"
        android:label="Music Library"/>
    <activity android:name=".Discover"
        android:label="Discover Music"></activity>
</application>
```

And here is the correct log:

> 11-15 14:45:13.248 10725-10725/com.example.alexcojocaru.vibes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.alexcojocaru.vibes, PID: 10725
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(144000000bytes) bitmap.
>                                                                                       at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
>                                                                                       at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
>                                                                                       at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:19381)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19317)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19114)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: That log tail is from google apps and not from your app.

Comment: Oh, ok haha... thanks, let me try again. Where do I need to look? I took this from logcat.

Comment: Please post manifest file. Need to check permissions.

Comment: Ok, just a moment.

Comment: And maybe this one. >Requires the VIBRATE permission https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html#vibrate(android.os.VibrationEffect)

Comment: You need to look in logcat but you need to look for stacktraces containing your app's package name (in your case that's `com.example.alexcojocaru.vibes`)

Comment: Do you use Vibrator related codes?

Comment: He said "No functionality" so I don't suspect he uses any. That also would not explain why it was working before the system wipe.

Comment: Looked just now, but I did not find anything with this string in the logcat.

Comment: I see. "Vibes" is his package name..

Comment: I don't use Vibrator related codes. Right now it's just xml code, no java. The app has multiple activity screens (3 at the moment), but the screens are not connected yet.

Comment: Then in the logcat select your application in the left drop down box and in the right one change from "No filter" to "Only show selected application". Then, let it crash again. You should see a red stacktrace. That's the one we're looking for.

Comment: "Vibes" is the name of the app that I am building. :-)

Comment: It looks like you have a large image in your app

Comment: Android does not have enough RAM for images that big. But btw nice name :)

Comment: I have removed that.

Comment: I updated the log tail, it seems it's a runtime error. Any ideas why? The large image is now removed.

Comment: I saw warning in your log about x86 incompatible, but seems deleted that part. Will you paste that part again? Also I saw InstantRun near that. What will happen if instant run is off?

Comment: I can't find that anymore. I think it was because of the big image, not that it's removed it doesn't show anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-studio-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap) post may help you. You seem to use a very large image somewhere, which is too large to draw on the android canvas.

Comment: Just checked drawable, the largest image now is 115 KB. Is this considered big?

Comment: i guess not but did you try the approach, which was suggested in the post? Maybe using Picasso can also solve your problem : http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: I tried and it fails the same... After I finish this project I will remove Android studio completely and try again with a clean install.