# Android Canvas trying to draw too large Exception

Tags: java, android

I am testing my app on 5 devices: Samsung Galaxy core, Samsung S6 edge, Moto G4, Xiaomi Redmi note 4 and Xiaomi MiA1. Loading bitmaps works fine on them but on some other it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large`. Can you help me find a solution?

Log:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw
>   too large(135788800bytes) bitmap.
>          at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
>          at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
>          at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
>          at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20338)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19283)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20061)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20341)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19283)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20061)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20061)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20061)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20061)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19274)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20061)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
>          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
>          at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20341)
>          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:979)
>          at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19283)
>          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
>          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
>          at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:800)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3447)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3234)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2769)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1738)
>          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7745)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Canvas: drawing too large bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-studio-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap)

Comment: If you have any large image in your drawable folder, then compress the image and then it will run perfectly.

Comment: too big image to draw. Phone can not allocated enough memory. Try yo use vector image or small size image, not high resolution.

Comment: `135788800bytes` / 1000 are 135788 kbytes / 1000 are 135 Mbytes, lets assume you have 4 bytes per pixel (ARGB), you have 135788800 / 4 = 33947200 and to assume a squared image: root of 33947200 = 5826. Are you really trying to draw an image with 5800x5800 pixels?

Comment: actually,I found the solution the real culprit was splash screen image, my designer did some sloppy work and gave me wrong sized images for splash screen, So i tested it on emulator and app crashed in big devices like Pixel xl-2 and in My colleague's phone. image size was not proper and it was causing crash , he gave me new images for that and now everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to compress your selected image before doing any action.

Here is the code that compress image with equal aspect ratio.

I converted Uri to bitmap

```
bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), uri);
```

The i pass the bitmap, maxwidth, minWidth to resize().

```
resizeBitmap = resize(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
```

resize() method

```
private static Bitmap resize(Bitmap image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
        float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

        int finalWidth = maxWidth;
        int finalHeight = maxHeight;
        if (ratioMax > ratioBitmap) {
            finalWidth = (int) ((float) maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
        } else {
            finalHeight = (int) ((float) maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
        }
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
        return image;
    } else {
        return image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you reduce the file size of your image by compressing it, the Bitmap shown on the phone will still take substantial amount of memory. [Bitmap renders every pixel independently](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/bitmaps/) and therefore a [4048x3036 pixels image can take up to 48 Mb of memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/)

The solution would be to reduce the resolution while maintaining desirable detail quality.

[Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Picasso to resize your image:

```
Picasso.get().load(imageUri).resize(512,512).into(imageView);
```

In resize method, the 2 numbers are the target width and height of your image. Change them as you like (but don't put too large numbers!).

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is using Glide:

```
Glide.with(context).load(uri).into(imageView);
```