# when starting app on samsung device it crashes with the following error

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

my app crashes everytime i start it on a samsung s7. On other devices i worked with it worked fine every time. It tells me, that a bitmap is to big:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.slartibartfast.kslordered, PID: 4800
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(106616832bytes) bitmap.
                  at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
                  at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20370)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                  at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1966)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20373)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19306)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20093)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
                  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20373)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:980)
                  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19315)
                  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
                  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
                  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:800)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3496)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3283)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1780)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7827)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I'm using images to get shown in a imageView.
Could you help me?
Could you help me?

Comment: You're getting error because, You're trying to draw image of very high resolution to your canvas. Please share code, so that i can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Canvas: drawing too large bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-studio-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This normally occurs when Image is exactly what logs say.Its too big.What I do is set all variations of the image i.e for `hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and xxxhdpi`. So while adding your image files, make sure there's one for each so each device oout there chooses the best density for itself.

Your images folder should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `samsung s7` you tested perhaps has lower resolution than other devices.

I suggest you compress this image, **106616832bytes** is definitely too big.