# Impossible to run app made for Api 28 (with minSdk 21) on <28 Api

Tags: java, android, api

I developped my app with my phone on Api 28 and never had any problem, now my app is quite finish so I build apk to test it and the installation fail on every phone that is not on Android 9 (Api < 28)

The result on the phone with Api 27 is " 'theApp' has working"

compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion are 28, minSdkVersion is 21 and the build is ok but it doesn't work even if the Api is 21 < xx < 28

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.penduleechecs"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

```
2019-06-19 16:17:43.020 966-966/com.example.penduleechecs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.penduleechecs, PID: 966
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(149743944bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1246)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18133)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18920)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4236)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4022)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19195)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:788)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: `Canvas: trying to draw too large(149743944bytes) bitmap` is unlikely to be tied directly to Android version. Somewhere,  you are trying to load a 149,743,944-byte bitmap, and you are not going to have sufficient memory for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare is right.  Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-studio-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap

Comment: Thank you for your answers but now i compressed all my images (<1 Mo) and the problem is still there, I don't have any folder named drawable-xxxhdpi, i have drawable (the pictures are there) and drawable-24 (don't know what it is)

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of the image resolution. The image which you are trying to use may be in a low-resolution folder. Try moving the image or bitmap to the next higher resolution image source.

For example, if your image is in the hdpi move it to xhdpi folder. 
The best method is to generate/import a resource as image/vector assest so that it will be allocated in respective folders for different resolution.

This will increase the apk size if you are generating one single apk. In this case, try to generate multiple apk for different resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your image from drawable to drawable-xxxhdpi. Maybe resolution is too high.

Hope it helps.