# My app keeps on stopping. It's a basic Login page. Logcat code is attached

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

> 2020-02-05 12:56:21.088
>   14966-14991/com.splash.splashactivityassingment E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008cdf 2020-02-05 12:56:21.089
>   14966-14991/com.splash.splashactivityassingment E/eglCodecCommon:
>   glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x00008824 2020-02-05 12:56:21.113
>   14966-14966/com.splash.splashactivityassingment E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.splash.splashactivityassingment, PID: 14966
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(228614400bytes) bitmap.
>           at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
>           at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:528)
>           at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1316)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17185)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16162)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16951)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3727)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3513)
>           at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17188)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:753)
>           at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16167)
>           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:648)
>           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
>           at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:762)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2800)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2608)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2215)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: check this line:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(228614400bytes) bitmap.

you are trying to use an image too big

Comment: Hi @Rohan , as you can read in, you are trying to use a Large bitmap (image). Try to get the image with less size, and try to use some libraries that will help you, like Glide or Picasso

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Canvas: drawing too large bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-studio-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show Bitmap on low resolution devices, resulting in crash.

> Process: com.splash.splashactivityassingment, PID: 14966
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too
>   large(228614400bytes) bitmap

You can make several images of different sizes (hdpi, xxdpi, etc.) or simply use an image loading and caching library to show your image, such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

```
ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Glide.with(this)
     .load(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.image))
     .into(img);
```