# I build an app in Android Studio i made it apk then installed in phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-debug, android-developer-api

i can not open that app after installation i get summary error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(127844352bytes) bitmap.
    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
    at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19218)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18168)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18946)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19221)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18168)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18946)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18159)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18946)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18159)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18946)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18159)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18946)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18159)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18946)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19221)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:791)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18168)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:685)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:691)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:799)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3056)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2851)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2404)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6886)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:841)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:772)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1015)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)

Comment: Possible duplicate. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-studio-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap

Comment: Thank you but it was Cause of Big Size omage

Answer (score 0):

From the description of the error, I guess some components in your projects aren't properly laid out.

E.g Text Field overflowing its required layout and so on.