# How to load HighRes images from URL without app crashing in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

So I made an app using the NASA RSS feed where I can browse through images of the day. Everything works fine until the app crashes because one of the images was too high res I believe.

This was the error: [image]

after some research I learned that I should create and use a drawable-xxxhdpi resource file which I did. However, theres nothing inside of it
[image]
The error states *"Class drawable should be defined"*

So what should I be typing inside the element to allow for High res images to be drawn without crashing?
Thank You!

Comment: try largeHeap = true in manifest

Comment: you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap

Comment: So one of the answers is : "moving the (hi-res) splash bitmap from drawable to drawable-xxhdpi was the solution." But what does that mean ?

Comment: You must downscale the image before presenting it to the user. Is there any reason you're not using Picasso (which is the most common image loading library)?

Comment: i am using picasso to load the images from the URL but im not using it to scale them.

Comment: yes it's one of it's core features. Just add `fit()` while building picasso request.

Comment: ah Yes! That worked thanks. Such a simple solution. Edited Original post for future users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION provided by @pawel I used picasso to load images from the URL but did not use it to scale the images. Pawel suggested I use .fit() and it worked

[image]