# Android Some mobile Error while opening the app

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey in my app there are some error while opening the app like this

java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(111513600bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:19484)
at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19420)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19217)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18176)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18954)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19229)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18176)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18954)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18167)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18954)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18167)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18954)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18167)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18954)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18167)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18954)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4240)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4024)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19229)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:791)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18176)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:685)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:691)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:799)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3056)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2851)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2404)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6886)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:841)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:772)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1015)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)

What will the solution for this. Please help
Thank you

Comment: Is your app on launch, show some image?

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635904/2930834