# Android resource buckets and the resolution strategy

Tags: android, android-resources

If I have an image that I put solely in `drawable-xxhdpi`, and no other buckets, does this pose any risk regards shipping to devices that have lower or higher densities?

Historically, we always produced an image variant for each bucket, `mdpi` through `xxxhdpi`. However recently an image was placed solely in `drawable` (which I believe is analogous to `drawable-mdpi`) and this understandably produced [out-of-memory issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap) when scaled up on certain devices.

The suggested approach in the answer to that question is to place said image in `drawable-xxhdpi` instead of `drawable`.

I'm fairly confident that this is acceptable but I would just like to validate that there are no problematic consequences here, including when the app is shipped and provisioned as a bundle (AAB). In particular is there any definitive documentation on the strategy for resolving bucketed resources?

Answer (score 0):

As far i know, if no `ldpi` resource is provided, `mdpi` resource would be taken.

For other types of resources it not guaranty, that it would work with only `drawable-xxhdpi`

First sources are looked in folder, that device supports (for example `drawable-hdpi`). If no resource found it looks in `drawable`

To use only one resource for all resolutions there should be used `drawable-anydpi`

But the pictures (png, jpg etc.) should be stored not in `drawable` better in `mipmap`, so at the end for one file for all resolutions `mipmap-anydpi` should be used.