# Compose landscapist GlideImage: throws java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(256576512bytes) bitmap

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-glide, android-13

I am using `com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:1.5.2` with `compose version 1.2.0-rc01` & `kotlin_version = "1.7.0"`,

I am loading list of member details with user profile image(from backend) in `LazyVerticalGrid` using `GlideImage` of size 120.dp only,
To update compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion to latest, **set latest API 33 from 31** & updated few image assets in the Project.

**This was working as expected for version less than Android 13 devices & emulators, but on Android 13 it throws:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(256576512bytes) bitmap.
```

**This crash is not showing from which part of code exception is thrown.**

I took reference of this post: [Android Canvas: drawing too large bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835514/android-canvas-drawing-too-large-bitmap)
I tried all possible solutions to fix the issue:

1. update landscapist-glide version to latest.
2. I also tried to compress placeholder image & splash image to small
   size of <10 Kb.
3. I also tried to convert images to SVG format and using as a vector
   drawable.
4. Move your image in the (hi-res) drawable to drawable-xxhdpi.

Any of these solutions did not work for me.

**I would like to know below points:**

1. **what is the solution for the same?**
2. **is there any Android 13 specific version update causing this issue due to some memory constraints?**

**Full Android Studio log cat in detail:**

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                     Process: com.tapamatch.app, PID: 29449
                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(256576512bytes) bitmap.
                    at android.graphics.RecordingCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(RecordingCanvas.java:266)
                    at android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseRecordingCanvas.java:98)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidCanvas.drawImageRect-HPBpro0(AndroidCanvas.android.kt:271)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.CanvasDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(CanvasDrawScope.kt:263)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs(Unknown Source:40)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.DrawScope.drawImage-AZ2fEMs$default(DrawScope.kt:510)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.BitmapPainter.onDraw(BitmapPainter.kt:93)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter.draw-x_KDEd0(Painter.kt:212)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.draw.PainterModifier.draw(PainterModifier.kt:281)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DrawEntity.draw(DrawEntity.kt:98)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:316)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:306)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:139)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:314)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:60)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:336)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:335)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:335)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:60)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:180)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:297)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.drawLayer(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:238)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:301)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:139)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:314)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:306)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.performDraw(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:139)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:314)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.draw(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:306)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.draw$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:839)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.performDraw(InnerPlaceable.kt:90)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeDrawScope.drawContent(LayoutNodeDrawScope.kt:48)
                    at androidx.compose.foundation.Background.draw(Background.kt:107)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.DrawEntity.draw(DrawEntity.kt:98)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:316)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.access$drawContainedDrawModifiers(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:60)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:336)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper$invoke$1.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:335)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
                    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)09:50:51.756  E   at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:335)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeWrapper.invoke(LayoutNodeWrapper.kt:60)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeApi29.record(RenderNodeApi29.android.kt:180)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.RenderNodeLayer.updateDisplayList(RenderNodeLayer.android.kt:297)
                    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchDraw(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:965)
                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:24409)
                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23267)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4732)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4704)
                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23214)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4732)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4704)
                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23214)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4732)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4704)
                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23214)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4732)
                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4704)
                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:23214)
                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:777)
                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:881)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:5647)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:5330)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4486)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3116)
                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:10885)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1301)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1309)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:923)
                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:852)
                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1283)
                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```