# Using android:largeHeap=“true” ? is a benefit or loss for an application that doesn't need it

Tags: android

I am not in favor of using `android:largeHeap=“true”`,
but i would like to know how much heap size boost can i expect from using the above property in manifest.
Will it give me infinite memory as much as my app requires or is has some limit too? 
My device is Moto X play, it has 192mb allocated memory. Its sufficient for my apps, but still am curious about knowing how much more heap size will `largeHeap` will give me ?

If my app only uses 100mb and i have used the `largeHeap="true"` will that have any disadvantages on the performance of my app. Will it effect other apps in my device, since am using only 100mb, will it still effect them.?

Does using `largeHeap` has any effects on the performance on my app, if yes, will the performance be better without it or with it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396892/what-are-advantages-of-setting-largeheap-to-true

Comment: actually, i read them and many other such topics on SO, i want to know that if my app uses very less memory and still i use this option, will that effect other apps ? or will that reduce my apps performance any how ?

Comment: If your app does not need more memory, then its better not to set this attribute beacuse, the memory is managed across all applications running on the device. Other important user applications might not get memory due to this. Thus can cause OutOfMemoryException