# Reduce video file size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using Xam.Plugin.Media to capture a photo and record a video. The problem is the file size of the video always above 20MB.

I tried to put the settings to the lowest still getting a 20MB file size for a 20 seconds video. I am using Samsung Galaxy A9 (2018). Can I use **FFMPEG** to reduce the file size?

```
private async void btnCamera4_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
   var cafNo = entCafNo.Text;
   TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 20, 0);

   await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

   if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakeVideoSupported)
   {
      await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "Ok");
      return;
   }

   try
   {
       var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(
       new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
       {
           Name = cafNo + "_VID.mp4",
           CompressionQuality = 0,
           Quality = VideoQuality.Low,
           DesiredLength = time
        });

        entVideoUrl.Text = file.Path;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Crashes.TrackError(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for android or forms? Because i see forms code but just asking as it will easy to answer then

Comment: @G.hakim I need it for forms

Answer (score 0):

If you see this awesome blog by [Xamarian's](http://blog.xamarians.com/Blog/2017/6/26/video-compression)

There is native code with how to use it for proper video compression natively. Since it is the native code you can also edit it as per your requirement.

In case of queries feel free to revert

Comment: I browsed on the comments and they said that ffmpeg is not working for api 6 and above I need to lower the file size because I am getting a out of memory exception

Comment: Ffmpeg was never an option did you check the guide in that answer?

Comment: I have fixed it I added LargeHeap Settings my problem now is the Java.Net.SocketException: Socket closed when sending the data to server

Comment: Setting LargeHeap is a bad practice but okay so the socketExpection stack trace would help here

Comment: what can I do to prevent using largeheap?

Comment: well there are a lot of things check this answer which explains it https://stackoverflow.com/a/30930239/7462031

Comment: What are the reason(s) why the socket is closing?

Comment: there could be n number of reasons I will need the stack trace to point it out to you