# Capture 5 images after a button click in android

Tags: android-camera

I am developing android application. The aim is to capture the 5 images after click a capture button. I am able to capture a single image by using the following code. But how can I take 5 images after a single button click. Please Can someone help me to do this?

Code snippet:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.camera.facedetectionexample.R;

public class FaceDetectionExample extends Activity {
    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE_CODE = 100;

    private Bitmap cameraBitmap = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.take_picture)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);
}

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(TAKE_PICTURE_CODE == requestCode){
                    processCameraImage(data);
            }
    }

private void openCamera(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_CODE);
}

private void processCameraImage(Intent intent){
    setContentView(R.layout.detectlayout);

    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.detect_face)).setOnClickListener(btnClick);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view);

    cameraBitmap = (Bitmap)intent.getExtras().get("data");

    imageView.setImageBitmap(cameraBitmap);
}

private View.OnClickListener btnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                        case R.id.take_picture:         
                            openCamera();   
                            break;
                }
        }
};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going to want to use burst mode, have a look at

[How to make burst mode available to Camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889271/how-to-make-burst-mode-available-to-camera)

should make it pretty clear.