# Take continous picture with one button android

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

What I'm trying to archive is: When user press a button (only 1 times), the camera will take 5,6 continous picture and save it to SD card.

Is there any way to do that? In my code, I'm calling a Camera Intent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889271/how-to-make-burst-mode-available-to-camera

Comment: You have to use a SurfaceView and SurfaceHolder and save bitmap rather than Camera Intent that use Camera App.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to launch an `intent` like so:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE);
startActivityForResult(mIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Please read up on [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html), and [Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for further details.

T Kwee